# Entity Framework 6 and MySQL base first

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I want to use exist db on `mysql` from `mvc asp.net`.
I installed `mysql plugin for vs` and `mysql connector net`.
Add connection string to config.
When I start vs in server explorer I see working connection, but when in project I try to add new `ado.net entity data model` -> `generate from database` wizard don't know about mysql in general, there are `defaultconnection to MS sql` and only two varients for new connection:

- Microsoft SQL Server
- Microsoft SQL Server Database file
- Other

Maybe I forgot something install?
Thanks for help.